# how to reduce the roundtrip to database in the keypress event for textbox in C#

Tags: c#

In my Windows Application i am using Text_box with List_box. When event fired in keypress event it retrieve the data  and listed in listbox

My problem is: For every keypress event hitting the database and application became slower.

How can i reduce the roundtrip the database in keypress event?

---

```
private void txtVehicleNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            lstVehicleNo.Visible = true;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtVehicleNo.Text))
            {
                dsResult = oclsBal.GetVhNo(txtVehicleNo.Text);
                if (dsResult.Tables.Count > 0)
                {

                    DataRow dr = dsResult.Tables[0].NewRow();
                    lstVehicleNo.DataSource = dsResult.Tables[0];
                    lstVehicleNo.DisplayMember = "VehicleNo";
                    lstVehicleNo.ValueMember = "VehicleId";
                    lstVehicleNo.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    dsResult.Tables.Clear();
                }

            }
            if (lstVehicleNo.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                lstVehicleNo.Visible = false;
            }
            if (txtVehicleNo.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                lstVehicleNo.Visible = false;
            }
            if (lstVehicleNo.Items.Count == 1)
            {
                if (txtVehicleNo.Text.ToUpper() == lstVehicleNo.Items[0].ToString().ToUpper())
                    lstVehicleNo.Visible = false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
       }
```

}

Comment: something like AutoComplete Text Box ? show us your codes

Comment: This might depend on the size and complexity of the data you are getting from the DB. There are different strategies dependent on the size of the data set. If the data set is small, you can get it once and cache it, for example. It also depends on if the dataset is more or less static, or is constantly updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only retrieve the list data after a timeout after the key is pressed, when a key is pressed, reset this timeout. This will mean only getting the data when there is a reasonable enough pause, when the user has stopped typing.

Alternatively use an auto-complete style box that pre-fetches any expected list items.

Answer (score 0):

For the first key-press, get all the records starting with that letter and keep it in cache or local memory and for further key presses you this cache. Since now you have a subset of data in local storage, you should get better performance.

Comment: i am not familar with cache concept Can u give me any Examples

Comment: Check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357.aspx
This should help